# Can masters function during Samadhi?

Tags: samadhi, enlightenment

Is there any type of Samadhi for any type of person, even jivanmukta, where he can walk and talk while being in the Samadhi.

Comment: Jivanmukti is the state and Jivanmukta is the person. Hence my edit.

Comment: Good edit. It also made me realize what I would rather ask than my original attempt. So edited it again.

Comment: Yes its now better.

Comment: Raghavendra Swanigal is alive in jiva samadhi he is in Mantralayam. There were several incident documented 1. Monroe spoke with the swamigal and documented in Madras Gazatte 2. Even now many people see him in their dream as well as physical form